In C++, what happens under the hood when an rvalue of a move-only type is passed to a function by value?
I am trying to understand value categories in C++ a bit better, and I encountered some code that got me a bit confused.
I looked at some questions such as Accept move-only parameter by value or rvalue reference or How is it possible to pass move-only types (e.g. std::unique_ptr) by value?, but I did not find any comment explaining what happens under the hood or why it is possible to pass as arguments rvalues of move-only types by value. Take the example below:
class Foo
{
  Foo(std::thread t) : mT(std::move(t))
private:
  std::thread mT;
};

int main()
{
  std::thread t;
  Foo f(t); // doesn't compile as std::thread is not copyable
  Foo f{std::thread()}; // compiles just fine using an rvalue
}

Calling Foo f(t); would call the non-existent copy-constructor of std::thread. However, what happens under the hood for the same not to happen when constructing a Foo object with the rvalue std::thread()? Why is the rvalue not copied?

std::thread doesn't have a copy constructor, but it do have a rvalue constructor. It's the one that will be used to create the object that is passed.


Why is the rvalue not copied?

The expression std::thread() is the initialisation of the parameter t. It is the same as why there isn't a copy when you write std::thread t;.
In the implementation of Foo::Foo, the object t is passed to std::move, which casts it to an rvalue reference, so that it matches std::thread::thread(std::thread&&), i.e. thread's move constructor.

"The expression std::thread() is the initialisation of the parameter t. It is the same as why there isn't a copy when you write std::thread t;"
Do you agree with @Someprogrammerdude as to t being constructed through the rvalue constructor? I am asking since it wasn't clear to me whether you were suggesting something different.

@FranciscoCastanheira no, t is constructed with the default constructor, std::thread() is direct-initialization. There isn't anything in between

From the second link you sent: "When a function is called, each parameter ([dcl.fct]) shall be initialized ([dcl.init], [class.copy], [class.ctor]) with its corresponding argument."
I wrote a small example to test this and it did have the move constructor being called. I will write it in a different comment, below.

@FranciscoCastanheira I'm talking about the construction of t (or foo in your other example), not the construction of mT (mFoo). That is default constructed from the initialiser. The data member is move-constructed from the parameter in the constructor, yes

Right, I missed that, thank you for the clarification!

For reference, this is the other code that I wrote:
https://pastebin.com/mG3Ye7hi
EDIT: and that I ended up deleting because I wrote it in a comment which messed up the formatting.
